# Где можно проверить сербское Милешево/Милешева?

Tags: топонимика

> Притча о Явлении Ангела жёнам у гроба Господня живёт во всех четырёх
>   Евангелиях. Однако евангелисты указывают разное количество
>   жен-мироносиц и явившихся им ангелов. Живописный рассказ церкви
>   Вознесения в Милешево ближе к слову Евангелия от Матфея...

Явление - с прописной?

И:

Косово, Сараево склоняются, если верить [Грамоте.ру](http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_1_toponimy/).

А с Мелешевом/ой непонятки...

Википедия рассказывает:

[Местоположение:    Милешево](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0)

> Монастырь Милешева — сербский православный монастырь на реке
>   Милешевце, близ Приеполья, основанный королем Стефаном Владиславом в
>   1218—1219 годах. Ансамбль фресок церкви Вознесения в Милешевой — один
>   из шедевров сербского искусства Средних веков.
>
> Храм Вознесения Христова в Милешевой принадлежит к архитектурному типу
>   рашской школы и представляет собой однонефную постройку простых
>   геометрических форм с трехчастной апсидой...

[Православие.ру](http://www.pravoslavie.ru/86519.html) списало у кого? О_о

> Сербский монастырь Милешева
>
> Монастырь Милешева основан в 1218—1219 годах сербским королем Стефаном
>   Владиславом, память которого празднуется 7 октября по новому стилю.
>   Именно сюда св.Владислав перенес из Болгарии земные останки своего
>   дяди - свт.Саввы Сербского. В Милешевой они почивали на протяжении
>   нескольких веков. Здесь же поныне находится место упокоения и самого
>   ктитора обители. Ансамбль фресок церкви Вознесения в Милешевой
>   относится к шедеврам сербского средневекового искусства.

Comment: Слово "явление" - общеупотребительное, это не религиозное название, пишется с маленькой буквы.

Comment: Учтём. Я автору строгое послание отправила: Люся пришла - изучай всё-всё-всё! А то видит вопрос о знаках - отмахивается: мол, всё одно ничего не пойму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Монастырь Милешева - окончание женского рода, потому что строилась обитель Милешева, а слово обитель устарело, стал монастырь, а название осталось, по традиции пишут окончание женского рода и склоняют как название женского рода - в Милешевой, имея в виду обитель. Но текст-то у вас не сербский, а русский, и имеется в виду посёлок, где находится обитель, т. е.

> Живописный рассказ церкви Вознесения в Милешево ближе к слову
>   Евангелия от Матфея.

— это верно.

Answer (score 1):

Косово и Сараево у нас с удивительной смелостью приравняли к русским посёлкам. При том, что традиция склонения наших деревень на -о не везде признаётся (хотя и навязывается директивно из  Центра), эти два  сербские названия даже по местоположению ударения отличаются от похожих русских (КосОво и СараЕво). Что касается *малоизвестных* названий, то этот их статус — дополнительный аргумент в пользу **несклонения**: как и у военных, оно позволяет восстановить название из других падежей. Я бы остановился на "монастырь в [городке] Милешево", если только официально не закреплено название "Милешевский монастырь". Вариант же *"монастырь Милешева"* (если исходить из склоняемости слова и даже примириться с похожестью его на фамилию) воспринимается не лучше, чем "**монастырь Петербурга**", - это принадлежность не населённого пункта, а религиозной общины (монашеской братии, сестринства и т. п.) или одной из таковых, базирующихся в нём.

Comment: *это принадлежность не населённого пункта, а религиозной общины* - Вы неправы. Против "Монастыря Нового Иерусалима" вы ничего против не имеете, надеюсь? Абсолютно тот же случай, к тому же подкрепляется сербской традицией. В Петербурге монастырей этих может быть несколько, а в маленьком городке - главная достопримечательность - да еще чуть ли не мирового значения...

Comment: @Alex_ander Саша, я даже не могу выяснить род топонима! И Вики, и Православие пишут: ***церкви Вознесения в Милешевой***. Как быть-то?

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova А где вы его выясняете-то?))) Топоним - Милешево. Читайте сербский вариант. Или на карту посмотирите. https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE&oq=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i60j69i61.903j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7kLerjhll4

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Вы на ютюбе выясняете род топонима? И еще говорите, что не можете выяснить???

Answer (score 0):

Да тут проверять-то нечего.
"Милешева" - родительный падеж в притяжательной функции. Ну как "Музеи Сараева". 
Вопрос в том, надо ли Милешево склонять... Но уж если склонять, то ***"Монастырь Милешева"*** и ***"Монастырь в Милешеве"***. Сами сербы так благополучно и делают. Про босняков того сказать не могу, ибо не знаю.

В Вики явно спутали притяжательную форму с топонимом женского рода.

Comment: Надо бы, наверно, подправить: _Мишлево, в Мишлеве, Мишлева, женским рода_.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова да, спасибо. *Мишлево, в Мишлеве, Мишлева* -  Это  уже другой городок, водится за мной такое.